# Cannot launch FSLint

Tags: python, dependencies, gtk, pip

Running Ubuntu 18.04 and want to try and run FSLint to clear some space, and I run into problems...

```
$ fslint-gui 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fslint-gui", line 27, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

I look this up and one suggestion is

```
$ pip install pygtk
Collecting pygtk
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/18/fa4f2de77500dd62a314fd845ff6e903ac2ce551164cb421c5750969f799/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zgzLmi/pygtk/
```

When that failed I tried `apt`.

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends python-gtk2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-gtk2 is already the newest version (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then I figured maybe the module is hidden in `dev`.

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends python-gtk2-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-gtk2-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Alright, I follow the dependency trail down and come to a dead end.

```
$ sudo apt install python-gtk2-dev libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxft-dev libfontconfig1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version (2.12.6-0ubuntu2.3).
libfontconfig1 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
```

or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfontconfig1 (= 2.12.6-0ubuntu2) but 2.12.6-0ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thoughts on how to solve this?

**Additional Info**

I installed this not too long ago with the simple `sudo apt install fslint`.

I ran the following according to N0rbert:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fslint libglade2-0 python-cairo python-glade2 python-gobject-2 python-gtk2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-cairo is already the newest version (1.16.2-1).
fslint is already the newest version (2.44-4ubuntu1).
libglade2-0 is already the newest version (1:2.6.4-2).
python-glade2 is already the newest version (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2).
python-gobject-2 is already the newest version (2.28.6-12ubuntu3).
python-gtk2 is already the newest version (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`which python` gave me `/usr/local/bin/python`

Just typing in `python` opened up

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 20 2019, 15:47:02)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux4
```

I have even tried a `purge` and `install` of `fslint` and none of the depandancies got reinstalled. I have even `sudo apt install -f` without success.

**Additional Updates for darksky**

> `Python 2.6.6`. That may be your problem. The default python 2 should be 2.7. Can you try `sudo apt install python2`, make sure it is 2.7 if you run `python2`, and then run `fslint-gui` again?

```
$ sudo apt install python2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2

$ sudo apt install python2[TAB]
python2.7            python2.7-doc        python2-pyro4
python2.7-dbg        python2.7-examples   python2-selectors34
python2.7-dev        python2.7-minimal    python2-serpent

$ sudo apt install python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt install python2.7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7-dev is already the newest version (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

> The fact that your python is sitting in `/usr/local/bin` and not `/usr/bin` tells me you or someone has manually installed it, probably from source.

I don't think I have done a source build. `make`s often than not result in missing dependencies. Does python come preinstalled when you first install a system? Maybe I should copy some files from my backup OS install (16.04).

> Also make sure to point your python to python2 by running sudo update-alternatives --config python and make sure it points to python2 or python2.7 and not anything with 2.6.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
```

Comment: When you see `you have held broken packages.`, try running `sudo apt install -f` to automatically resolve these dependency problems. I am not sure how you installed `fslint` but on Ubuntu 19.10, when I run `sudo apt install fslint`, it automatically installs the dependencies `libglade2-0 python-cairo python-glade2 python-gobject-2 python-gtk2`. You should not have to install anything manually.

Comment: Do  you have changed the system-wide python2 version? Please add output of `which python` to the question. Do you have any errors while running `sudo apt-get install fslint libglade2-0 python-cairo python-glade2 python-gobject-2 python-gtk2`?

Comment: `Python 2.6.6.` That may be your problem. The default python 2 should be 2.7. Can you try `sudo apt install python2`, make sure it is 2.7 if you run `python2`, and then run `fslint-gui` again?

Comment: The fact that your python is sitting in `/usr/local/bin` and not `/usr/bin` tells me you or someone has manually installed it, probably from source. It didn't get installed by `apt`. How have you installed python on your machine?

Comment: Also make sure to point your `python` to `python2` by running `sudo update-alternatives --config python` and make sure it points to `python2` or `python2.7` and not anything with 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 18.04 distribution's default python 2 version has always been 2.7. If you simply run `sudo apt install python` in 18.04, you should end up with a python 2.7 in your `/usr/bin` which is soft-link to `/usr/bin/python2.7`. You have *somehow* installed python2.6 in your `/usr/local` which seems to have taken precedence over 2.7. First thing you need to do is make sure 2.7 is again the default.

An easy way would be to simply rename your `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/local/bin/python2.6`. If there is a `/usr/local/bin/python2` you might want to remove that as well. In the end when you do `which python` you should see `/usr/bin/python`. And if you run `ll /usr/bin/python` you should see `/usr/bin/python -> python2.7*`. You can additionally create `python2` by `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2` for further compatibility with programs that require `python2` specificly.

Python is a crucial component of your operating system, and there are *a lot* of packages that depend on it, including the program `fslint`. For this reason, you may end up with weird dependency issues if your system-wide python isn't what is normally shipped with 18.04.

Lastly, you do not need the `-dev` version of python since you are not compiling anything that depends on python headers from source.

Comment: Going by this, I found a python and a python2.6 in the local bin. I mv'd the python to python2.7, did a reinstall of python, and now fslint works. Thanks for pointing these files out.